# How to fix layout to browser window without scroll

Tags: html, css

For a particular web app I'm working on, there sometimes what can be a long long table.  What I'm attempting to do is implement a view mode, that will force the table only to take up what space is left on the screen and have its own scrollbar.

To strip things down, I've created a little test bit of html which mimics my layout with 2 fixed height elements, and then a 3rd element which may grow depending how many child elements are within.

What I'm trying to accomplish with this code is have the whole layout ONLY occupy the size of the browser window, and if needed show a scrollbar in the expanding element.

If anyone can help with the css here, it would be greatly appreciated. #grid is the element that I want to show in its own scrolling div, and not expand past the window height, causing the window scrollbars to show.

I've shared a jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/kPG3J/

```
<style>
#toolbar {border:1px solid red; height:150px;width:100%}
#chart {border:1px solid green; height:350px;width:100%}
#grid{border:1px solid blue; height:auto;width:100%}
#wrapper {min-height:100%;height:100%;}
#grid {overflow:scroll}
html {height:100%}
body {height:100%; margin:2em } 
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="toolbar">Tool bar</div>
    <div id="chart">The Chart</div>
    <div id="grid">
        <p>Grid data </p>
        <p>Grid data </p>
        <p>Grid data </p>
        <p>Grid data </p>
        <p>Grid data </p>
        <p>Grid data </p>
        <p>Grid data </p>
        <p>Grid data </p>                
        <p>Grid data </p>
        <p>Grid data </p>
        <p>Grid data </p>
        <p>Grid data </p>
        <p>Grid data </p>
        <p>Grid data </p>
        <p>Grid data </p>
        <p>Grid data </p>                
    </div>
</div>


</body>
```

Comment: Dave, could you please make a jsfiddle?

Comment: sure thing - I love jsfiddle.. never think of using it myself though!  http://jsfiddle.net/kPG3J/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No javascript needed. However, you may need to shrink the height of your div's on top to make it practical. Here's modified CSS that works (not fully tested in all browsers):

```
#toolbar {border:1px solid red; height:150px; width:100%;}
#chart {border:1px solid green; height:250px; width:100%;}
#grid{border:1px solid blue; width:100%;}
#wrapper {position: absolute; top: 2em; left: 2em; bottom: 2em; right: 2em;}
#grid {overflow: auto; position: absolute; top: 404px; bottom: 0;}
html {height: 100%}
body {margin: 0; height: 100%; }
```

The `top` position is set to height of upper two divs and the border amounts. "Margins" is handled by the positioning of the `wrapper` div, not the `body` element

Comment: very nice. It even handles browser resizing perfectly, something not even the javascript solution would do (unless he handles a browser resize event).

Comment: It would never have occurred to me to put a height on `html`. Well done.

Answer (score 2):

Change to this:

```
#grid {height:200px;overflow:scroll}
```

Set height according to what you want.

If you want to set the height to the browser's height, you'll need to use Javascript's `screen.height`

http://jsfiddle.net/yNCkA/

You can use this javascript to get the height your element should be:

```
<script>
    function setHeight()
    {
       var height = screen.height - 300; // 300 = 150 (chart) + 150 (graph)
       document.getElementById('grid').style.height = height + "px";           
    }
</script>
```

Your HTML:

```
<body onload="setHeight()">
    <!-- html goes here -->
</body>
```

If Javascript is not an option, you can do one of the following:

1. Develop the page assuming a minimum resolution of 1024x768. According to a [survey](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_display.asp),  99% of the people are using a resolution of 1024x768 or higher.
2. Set your body height to 100%. Set `graph` and `chart` heights to 15% each, and set `grid` height to 70%. However, this means `graph` and `chart` won't always be `150px`.

Comment: I suspected javascript might be the only way to go.  Thanks

Comment: No need to switch to percentages for non-javascript solution. See my answer.